# Eagle PCB design: wire names for multiple power/gnd pins

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I am working on a schematic using Eagle (free version, v7.5) for a part that has multiple VCC/VBAT pins with each pin requiring a decoupling capacitor. Currently, my schematic looks like the one below, with 3.3V tag connected to all power pins and decoupling caps attached directly to the part instance (U1).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCW7GH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For better documentation and cleaner schematic, I would like to attach tags to the power pins in the part instance, and then separately connect each tag to 3.3V and corresponding decoupling cap. Something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVdZ1w.png)</sup>

Can I insert multiple tags on a wire in Eagle? Or is there any other way I could achieve the same objective of cleaner schematic / better documentation?

Comment: This should not be done, a wire should have a unique node, as it is the net name. Either label the remote caps or leave them as you had them. The first way shows what the caps are intended for better.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without relying on self-added labels you can do the following:

**Warning: it is ugly and I do not recommend doing this.**

Create a new part which looks like a dead short:

[image]

The package is simply two pads overlapping (this will generate a DRC error of course) so the two pins are automatically connected later in the layout.

You can now connect two different labels with the part:

[image]

You can also change the color of the part so it does not stand out too much:

[image]

Sadly, I do not know any other way of achieving what you want.